# Bash command to send line by line over netcat

Tags: python, sockets, netcat, tshark

I am trying to send tshark output with this command with netcat to a receiving socket:

`sudo tshark -l -Y dns -T fields -e ip.id src port 53 | while read -r line; do echo "$line" | nc 127.0.0.1 12345 ; done`

So each packet is one line and each line is sent to the server socket. My problem is, that this command only sends the first packet/line and then stops sending. Eventhough tshark keeps an capturing packet.
With which command can I send each line over a netcat connection?

Thank you

EDIT: I managed to partly solve my problem by deleting the while loop from the command. The problem is, that now netcat sends the socket multiple lines. My plan is to tell netcat to send each line separately. How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you sure that problem is not on other size ? Maybe server can receive only one line and you can't changing it using `nc` - you have to change code on server.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by deleting the while loop.

Comment: if you resolved your problem then you can put it as answer and later you can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: if `recv()` is used only once (without loop) then it will receive only one line. You should rather check code in server.